# Blessing on a food or a drink first?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, priorities

If someone has in front of them a food and drink that the bracha (blessing) of both is shehakol which one should he make a blessing on first? Assuming that he doesn't prefer one over the other. Is there a reason to make a bracha on the food first before the drink?

(I have no reason to think a bracha should be made on the food first if they are both shehakol however I've heard that perhaps the Caf HaChaim speaks about this and have not found it. Perhaps there are other poskim as well that address this issue or savaras (reasoning) one way or another.)

Answer (score 4):

The [Aruch HaShulchan in Siman 211 Sif 17](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7705&st=&pgnum=397) writes that a bracha should be made on food before a drink (he says "nira li" that it "appears" to him.)

The Pri Megadim in his Pesicha to Hilchos Brachos Sif 8 writes that there is no "priority" given between a food and a drink when it comes to which one a bracha should be made on first.

Comment: I'm still looking for more achronim that perhaps spoke about this shaila

Answer (score 3):

The *P'ri M'gadim* rules that one need not prioritize a *b'racha* on solid food over a *b'racha* on a drink ([*Mishb'tzos Zahav* 211:6](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1111)):

> ואכילה לשתיה אין בו קדימה אם ברכותיהן שוות רק בחביב ורוצה עתה

The *Yafeh Sha'ah* ([OC § 17](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21957&pgnum=49)) also writes that one need not prioritize a *b'racha* on solid food over a *b'racha* on a drink, and one might infer the same from the *Be'er Moshe*'s ([Vol. 1, § 11](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=887&st=&pgnum=29)) treatment of the *Magen Avraham* and the *Mishna B'rura*.

As mentioned in [Yehoshua's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/30063), the *Aruch HaShulchan* ([OC 211:17](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7705&st=&pgnum=397), ונ"ל דאכילה קודם לשתייה) is of the opinion that a *b'racha* on food takes precedence over a *b'racha* on a drink.

Comment: This answer is essentially copied and pasted from parts of my answer [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23526).